# How to wait for multiple locators to be visible

Tags: playwright

When waiting for a single `Locator` to be visible this can be with a simple `expect().toBeVisible()` but how would I wait for multiple and independent locators to be visible at the same time?
In the following example el1 might be initially visible but while waiting for el2 to be visible el2 might no longer be and I would like to ensure that both elements are visible at the same time.

```js
test('visible', async ({page}) => {
   const el1 = page.locator('.el1');
   const el2 = page.locator('.el2');

   await expect(el1).toBeVisible();
   await expect(el2).toBeVisible();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.toPass()](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#retrying) from v1.29 for this which will retry until all assertions pass or the timeout is met:

```
await expect(async () => {
    const el1 = page.locator('.el1');
    const el2 = page.locator('.el2');

    await expect(el1).toBeVisible();
    await expect(el2).toBeVisible();
}).toPass({
    timeout: 10000,
});
```

Comment: But wouldn't this assertion also pass when `el1` is visible, Playwright waits for `el2`, `el1` disappears and `el2` becomes visible?

Comment: @stefanjudis No. Both assertions must pass inside on the retry for it to pass.  If el1 was visible on retry 1 and el2 was not, it would fail and retry.  If on the next retry el1 was not visible, it would immediately fail and go for another retry until both are visible or timeout us met.